# How (and where) to report a web site distribute a program with a virus?

Tags: virus, antivirus

I came across this free video converter program for Windows called [Any video converter](https://www.any-video-converter.com) and installed it, my antivirus program immediately found a virus within it (Win32:Evo-gen). 
**How and where can I report that site distributes its program with a built-in virus?**

Comment: Look for the WHOIS of the website (Google for how to do that). That should provide you with an abuse email to send a message to, or at least the name of a company whose website has a link to their abuse email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reporting the website in question to the relevant host (discovered by running a WHOIS as suggested by forest in their comment), you can also report the website to Google using their [Report malicious software](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/) form. In the case of a phishing site the [Report Phishing Page](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/) form should be used.

If your report is reviewed and accepted, the page will be excluded from Google's search results, and anyone using Google Chrome will get a warning page from Google's [Safe Browsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/) and will be deterred from continuing. I *believe* that Chrome may also prevent the user from opening the executable downloaded from the website if the user ignores the big red warning page.

Comment: If site registered with GoDaddy, you can report it here https://supportcenter.godaddy.com/AbuseReport